# Annoying space before/after the text on headers

Tags: context

Friends, why when \doiftextelse and \startsetups are used (to get the names of chapters, section, etc.) into an environment you get an annoying space before/after the text on headers. But when the same code is applied out of any environment, it just works?

[image]
[image]

MWE:

```
\startsetups[chapterinfo]
\doiftextelse{\getmarking[chapter]}{\getmarking[chapter]}{\getmarking[chapter]}
\stopsetups
\setupheadertexts[{\setup[chapterinfo]}][][][{\setup[chapterinfo]}]

\showframe
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\startsectionblockenvironment[frontpart]
\startsetups[chapterinfo]
\doiftextelse{\getmarking[chapter]}{\getmarking[chapter]}{\getmarking[chapter]}
\stopsetups
\setupheadertexts[{\setup[chapterinfo]}][][][{\setup[chapterinfo]}]
\stopsectionblockenvironment

\starttext

\startfrontmatter
\startchapter[title={Chapter}]
\dorecurse{15}
{\input knuth}
\stopchapter
\stopfrontmatter

\startchapter[title={Chapter}]
\dorecurse{15}
{\input knuth}
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, spaces are not ignored when `\start...\stopsetups` is used inside `\start...\stopsectionblockenvironment`.  If you want to use square brackets with `\start...\stopsetups` you also have to hide the succeeding space by `\startsetups[chapterinfo]%`.

```
\startsetups chapterinfo
  \doiftextelse{\getmarking[chapter]}{\getmarking[chapter]}{\getmarking[chapter]}
\stopsetups
\setupheadertexts[{\setup[chapterinfo]}][][][{\setup[chapterinfo]}]

\showframe
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\startsectionblockenvironment[frontpart]
  \startsetups chapterinfo
    \doiftextelse{\getmarking[chapter]}{\getmarking[chapter]}{\getmarking[chapter]}% <-- hide this space
  \stopsetups
  \setupheadertexts[{\setup[chapterinfo]}][][][{\setup[chapterinfo]}]
\stopsectionblockenvironment

\starttext

\startfrontmatter
  \startchapter[title={Chapter}]
    \dorecurse{15}{\input knuth}
  \stopchapter
\stopfrontmatter

\startchapter[title={Chapter}]
  \dorecurse{15}{\input knuth}
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Without `%`

[image]

With `%`

[image]

## Alternative

I don't think this is a bug, because setups are meant to be declared on global scope.  Therefore I would declare the two setups globally and give them different names, also revealing where they are to be used.

```
\startsetups chapterinfo:main
  \doiftextelse{\getmarking[chapter]}{\getmarking[chapter]}{\getmarking[chapter]}
\stopsetups

\startsetups chapterinfo:front
  \doiftextelse{\getmarking[chapter]}{\getmarking[chapter]}{\getmarking[chapter]}
\stopsetups

\setupheadertexts[{\setup[chapterinfo:main]}][][][{\setup[chapterinfo:main]}]

\showframe
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\startsectionblockenvironment[frontpart]
  \setupheadertexts[{\setup[chapterinfo:front]}][][][{\setup[chapterinfo:front]}]
\stopsectionblockenvironment

\starttext

\startfrontmatter
  \startchapter[title={Chapter}]
    \dorecurse{15}{\input knuth}
  \stopchapter
\stopfrontmatter

\startchapter[title={Chapter}]
  \dorecurse{15}{\input knuth}
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Comment: Thanks Henri, what about the space before the text?

Comment: @jl4c This only occurs when you use square brackets around the name of the setup.  To get rid of it add a percent after the closing bracket as in `\startsetups[chapterinfo]%`.  I suggest, you use my alternative approach in the second part of the answer.